# AdMob Adview overlaps TableRow button caption

Tags: android, xml, layout, admob, android-scrollview

I've been working on a soundboard like application using the following layout

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/adView">
            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >
                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                >
    <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:stretchColumns="0,1">
    <TableRow...>
    <TableRow...>
    <TableRow...>
    <TableRow...>
    <TableRow...>
    ....(some more rows, all of them with two buttons in each one)

     </TableLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

When the main activity is created, i set the layout and load the ad into the adview.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8;
        Toolbar mToolbar;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
        {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

The problem I've been having is that when the application is launched for the first time, when the ad banner is being loaded, if I decide to scroll to the bottom, once the ad is being shown, it overlaps the caption of the last two buttons. But once the ad is refreshed ( 30 seconds is the actual time of refresh), or I press the 'Back' button and re-enter the application, somehow the missing captions are no longer covered by the banner.

See pictures attached. I'd like to know if there's something I can change from the layout or from the code in order to avoid having this problem when the application is loaded for the first time.

[Correct layout after refresh of banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P9JN.jpg)

[Banner overlaping the caption of the last buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOXYf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Add a bottom margin of 50 px to the `TableLayout` and leave out the space for banner to avoid inconsistent displays.

```
 <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1">
```

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get what you meant with 'leave out the space for banner'. I added the bottom margin but still got the same problem. I assume that there's something else I had to do but I don't know what is.

Comment: Reserve the space for banner

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean, but I don't know how to do it. It's something I can do within the xml layout or it's on the java code ?

Comment: Yes in the XML. Change the table layout as shown in my answer. Add the layout margin ...

Comment: I've added the marginBottom property to the TableLayout, but I still have the same issue, that's why I thought that something else was missing since that addition alone didn't solve the problem.